# Can't use page_token in search_all_resources (GCP python-asset)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, iterator

I am trying to iterate the search_all_resources pager and getting the following exception.

```
    from google.cloud import asset_v1
    client = asset_v1.AssetServiceClient()

    next_page_token = 0
    while next_page_token is not None:
        params = {
            "scope": parent
        }
        if next_page_token != 0 and next_page_token is not None:
            params['page_token'] = next_page_token
        
        response = client.search_all_resources(**params)
        assets = list(response)
        total_assets.append(assets)
        next_page_token = response.next_page_token
```

> Exception: search_all_resources() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'pageToken'

**Environment details**

- Python version: 3.8
- google-cloud-asset: 2.0.0 (https://github.com/googleapis/python-asset)

Comment: You are calling the API wrong. Refer to the documentation for this text: `Search all resources response. Iterating over this object will yield results and resolve additional pages automatically.` You do not need to play with the `next_page_token`. https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudasset/latest/asset_v1/services.html

Comment: Please follow the link [1], it seems there already have a solution about the issue:
[1] https://github.com/googleapis/python-asset/issues/83